# Extract String from ArrayList which get the item from listview

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I want to extract string from the arraylist of String which is filled by the selected items from the listView.
The result of the array list is:

```
     {studentName=XXX,studentID=SF10001}
     {studentName=YYYY,studentID=SF10002}
```

I want only get the studentID which are SF10001 and SF10002. Below is my code:

```
     SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
     ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
        // Item position in adapter
        int position = checked.keyAt(i);
        // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
        if (checked.valueAt(i))
            selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));
    }

    String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {

            outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);

    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            ResultActivity.class);

    // Create a bundle object
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);

    // Add the bundle to the intent.
    intent.putExtras(b);

    // start the ResultActivity
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

And this the Result Activity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] resultArr = b.getStringArray("selectedItems");

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.outputList);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resultArr);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

@SoulRayder
So, I had created a StudentData Class:

```
public class StudentData implements Serializable {
String studentName;
String studentID;

public String getStudentNameStudentData() {
    return studentName;

}

public String getStudentID()
{
    return studentID;
}
```

And I change the code like tis：

```
    SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();

    ArrayList<StudentData> selectedItems = new ArrayList<StudentData>();

    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
        // Item position in adapter
        int position = checked.keyAt(i);
        // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
       if (checked.valueAt(i))

            selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));
    }

    String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {

            outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i).getStudentID();

    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            ResultActivity.class);

    // Create a bundle object
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);

    // Add the bundle to the intent.
    intent.putExtras(b);

    // start the ResultActivity
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

But this code show me error:

```
 selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));
```

which is ArrayList cannot applied to (java.lang.String). How to solve the problem.
BTW, thanks your immediate respond :D

Comment: You have an Arraylist of strings... Making this harder than it needs to be. Make a Student class. Store that in a list that you can filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways of solving your problem :

1) *Simpler* way , but not *efficient*: (You can use this if all your strings are *guaranteed* to use that exact template, or add further validations to the below function)

```
 public string extractStudentID(string input)
 {
      string [] parts = input.substring(1,input.length-1).split(",");

      return parts[1].split("=")[1];
 }
```

and use it in your code as follows

```
 for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
    // Item position in adapter
    int position = checked.keyAt(i);
    // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
    if (checked.valueAt(i))
        selectedItems.add(extractStudentID(adapter.getItem(position)));
}
```

2) Create a class for you student data

```
class StudentData
{
       public string studentName;
       public string studentID;
}
```

Use an arraylist of these objects, instead of an arraylist of strings and modify your code in all other places accordingly:

```
 ArrayList<StudentData> selectedItems = new ArrayList<StudentData>();
```

Then, at any point, you can access the student ID easily by

```
 selectedItems.get(index).studentID;
```

Comment: i updated the code also some problem thr. please hlp solve :D

Comment: @Lai : You also need to make sure that your adapter stores the student data in the same signature of your class (that is it should handle StudentData). If you ensure this, then you can use that faulty line of code as is. Currently it is complaining because adapter.getItem(position) returns a string and not a StudentData object, since your list is a list of StudentData objects. If you make it return a StudentData object, then the code should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I chged my way to solve this problem but the another problem occur. If you can help, can you help me have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660410/change-the-listview-in-arrayadapter-become-multiple-choice-listview-in-arrayadap . Thanks ::D

Comment: You need to add the checkbox element inside your listitem definition within the  correspondong xml. Then only would the checkbox show up for each list item. You can access the checkbox similarly to how you are accessing the textview elements.